# clarification about ながら and だが being linked together

Tags: grammar, sentence

> 幾重にも、幾重にも、その手を血の色で上塗りしていきながら、だが男は決して怯まなかった。

Can one use ながら and だが together ? this seems rather perplexing to me .

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the combination of ながら and だが/しかし is used, but mainly in literary works. I checked BCCWJ and the majority of examples were from literary works. This combination is interchangeable with ながらも, which is already a stiff expression, but ながら+だが/しかし sounds considerably more "dramatic" to me.

- 口調は穏やかながらも、目は笑っていない。
  口調は穏やかながら、しかし目は笑っていない。
- 彼女は貧しいながらも幸せな生活を送った。
  彼女は貧しいながら、だが幸せな生活を送った。